# How to customise Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.User.props for VS2017?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

Traditionally we've been able to setup the Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.User.props file to help us have different setups for different versions of Visual Studio by using PlatformToolset:

Visual Studio 2012 = v100

Visual Studio 2013 = v120

Visual Studio 2015 = v140

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0">
  <PropertyGroup Condition="$(PlatformToolset) == 'v100'">
    <IncludePath>C:\SDKs\boost_1_53_0;$(IncludePath)</IncludePath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="$(PlatformToolset) == 'v120'">
    <IncludePath>C:\SDKs\boost_1_59_0;$(IncludePath)</IncludePath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="$(PlatformToolset) == 'v140'">
    <IncludePath>C:\SDKs\boost_1_64_0;$(IncludePath)</IncludePath>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

But I can't figure out how I can do this for Visual Studio 2017. What version of
PlatformToolset is it using, or has it dropped that completely?

Comment: It is pretty visible when you play with the Platform Toolset setting in a project, available on the General page.  The names are shown in (parentheses).  So it is v141.  Do be careful with this, your project isn't going to build on another machine or a year or two from now.  Never a very desirable property of a project :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found this in my .vcxprof file:

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>StaticLibrary</ConfigurationType>
    <PlatformToolset>v141</PlatformToolset>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Using PlatformToolset = v141 works fine.